# How to change the default open file dialog path

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio (I'm using 2010) is there a way to change which folder pops up by default when you go to open a file?

Comment: Any idea how to do this for Visual Studio 2017? There is still no setting for the regular Ctrl+O (Open File), and the I cannot find the registry key for this version.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

For **Visual Studio 2017 and 2019** you'll have to navigate from 
**Tools->Options (Alt+T, O)** then **Projects and Solutions->Locations**, there are 3 Locations but you will only need to edit the **Projects location** and click **OK**. No need to restart VS.

Comment: Interesting - not sure if this is a bug in 15.8.1, but when I update this location, and click Open Project, it's going to a folder from the last project I created, but ignoring the default, and all the projects I've opened since then. I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: @JasonBeck I'm on 15.8.2 and it works fine. I can confirm that the Folder "Location" which is shown in the New Project Window is set to the last folder used to create a project/solution by default (this could be a Bug). But when I use Open Project it starts by the folder I have set in the described Options.

Comment: For me this solution did work when opening a Project (ctrl+shift+O) but not for opening a File (ctrl+O). However the answer of @Michael Beaton did work.

Comment: @TimSchmidt Same here, solution works for ctrl+shift+o but not ctrl+o.

Comment: This didn't work for me with ctrl+O either, and the only numbered regedit key for me  under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio` is `15.0` which doesn't have any of those values. However once I deleted the folder that ctrl+O kept opening to (source\repos under my user dir), it then picked up my "Projects" folder under Location option.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I really needed. I pretty much only do "Open Project or Solution" from the initial splash screen and this appears to be that location. I first did the registry change (VS 2019, v16.9) and that didn't do anything for that splash screen open location but maybe restarting Windows would. Either way this is the one I really wanted so thanks.

Comment: This holds true for VS 2022, as well.

Answer (score 27):

There are a bunch of file locations in the registry at HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0. The one you need to change is DefaultFileOpenLocation.

Comment: I upvoted this years ago and forgot about it, have since replaced my hard drive and reinstalled VS, Googled to fix it, and found this answer again.  I wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: Don't forget to close VS before changing paths, otherwise VS will overwrite them.

Comment: Still extremly useful. Works for all version including VS 2019 (version 16.0). If the DefaultFileOpenLocation does not exist, create it and it works.

Answer (score 13):

Yes in Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->General

Comment: Thanks, I have all the paths set in there but when I go to open a file it goes to the default.  Creating a new project or whatever works properly but I'm talking about opening an existing file.

Comment: Make sure to check "Show All Settings" or "Projects and Solutions" will not show.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could configure Visual Studio 2019 Professional was through the "[Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs)" with vsregedit.exe as explained in [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/722325/visual-studio-2019-changing-default-location-for-s.html). Adding to the windows registry didn't work.

Among the windows registry entries for VS2015 in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0`, there used to be these:

```
DefaultFileOpenLocation
DefaultOpenProjectLocation
DefaultOpenProjItemLocation
DefaultOpenSolutionLocation
DefaultNewProjectLocation
DefaultNewProjItemLocation
VisualStudioLocation
VisualStudioProjectsLocation
```

You can change any of these keys using vsregedit. Some of these can be changed from the interface, in Tools->Options, Projects and Solutions->Locations or through the [Git Settings for the Default Repository Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134077/visual-studio-change-default-path-for-repositories-for-git-plugin). The ones I had to change through vsregedit were:

```
DefaultFileOpenLocation
DefaultNewProjItemLocation
DefaultOpenProjItemLocation
```

You can read the current values with:

```
vsregedit read local HKCU "" DefaultNewProjItemLocation string
```

The output is something like:

```
Name: DefaultNewProjItemLocation, Value: %USERPROFILE%\source\repos
```

To change the values, you can use:

```
vsregedit set local HKCU "" DefaultFileOpenLocation string "C:\Visual Studio Projects"
vsregedit set local HKCU "" DefaultNewProjItemLocation string "C:\Visual Studio Projects"
vsregedit set local HKCU "" DefaultOpenProjItemLocation string "C:\Visual Studio Projects"
```

Now when we read any of the modified keys, it will show:

```
Name: DefaultNewProjItemLocation, Value: C:\Visual Studio Projects
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click the open project button the dialog that pops up defaults to something strange, I've yet to be able to figure it out (I think it might be because I am using Dropbox).  At any rate, clicking the Projects link on the left (the red arrow points to it) will take you directly to the directory you specified to put new projects in.  This is Windows 7 64-bit with SP1. YMMV

[image: Win7 Open File Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

Also works for VS 2013. Root registry key is HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS 2017 and was being brought to the same directory time and time again, one I had not opened for a few months despite opening and creating dozens of projects afterwards.  I tried resetting via Tools > Options, but to no avail.  I finally created a txt file in the directory I wanted as my default and opened that through the dialog and now it's working again.