# Can I get VS2010 to look at VSS when I click Open Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My VS2010 environment has the start page come up if I'm not opening a solution.  From there, I can open one of the several items on the recent projects list or I can open a project from the link/button in the upper left.  When I do that, I get an Open Project dialog that's pointed at my C:\workingvss (which is a convention that everyone on my team follows for where our code lives locally).  But I virtually always want to browse to the project in a VSS database and I have to scroll up in the left-hand pane of the dialog to bring 'Microsoft Visual SourceSafe' into visibility.  It seems dumb that I can't make it just start at the top of the pane, but if there's a way, I haven't been able to figure out how.

So I'm turning to you.  Is there something I can do to avoid this click and drag every time I want to open a project?

I realize it's defaulting to the Projects location parameter set through Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General.  But I think I need to leave that as is because I *do* want my stuff saved to that location during checkout.

I also think that if I removed ten (in my case) folders from the root of my C:, the left pane would show my VSS option, but I don't think that's even possible in this machine's case and not a reasonable solution in any case.

My question is related to, but not a duplicate of, [How to change the default open file dialog path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742723/how-to-change-the-default-open-file-dialog-path).

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a great answer, but it's my current no-tech work-around.  If I make the Open Project dialog large enough to accommodate all of the lines it wants to display, then my VSS line is visible and I don't have to navigate to it.  Luckily, Visual Studio remembers the size from use to use.