# Visual Studio: Change default path for repositories for GIT plugin

Tags: git, visual-studio

I want to clone a GitHub repository from Visual Studio, and the default path is `C:\Users\[User]\Sources\Repos\[NameOfProject]`.

[image: Snapshot]

How do I change it? Every time I create or clone a repo, the path remains the same.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

**In Visual Studio 2015 / 2017 / 2019:**

1. Go to the menu bar, click View and then select Team Explorer
2. Click the Home icon button in Team Explorer
3. Click on Settings
4. Click on Global Settings under Git
   (Note: may not appear if you have no cloned git repos)
5. Alter the path for the Default location.
6. Click OK/Update

**Note: the location is case-sensitive, and it will not warn you if that exact location is not found**

Comment: This should be the correct answer as the names in the instructions completely match those found in Visual Studio.

Comment: For me it said Offline and offered no option because I hadn't cloned a repository yet. Even though I wanted to change a global repository setting, not a local one.

Comment: If you don't see the settings for Git, go into Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection, and set it to Git

Comment: Is there a way to set it automatically for several users?

Comment: -->2. At first glance, I didn't see the settings. the menu is behind the headline "Connect" in the Git Team Explorer.
@scls you could try to export and restore the vs.settings

Comment: Don't forget to click the Update button, these settings don't auto-save.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 16.8.3: Tools > Options > Source Control > Git Global Settings > Default location

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 16.11.10 : 'Teams Explorer' is found under 'View' in the top menu.

Answer (score 47):

In addition to the Team Explorer's Git settings...

[image]

...you'll likely want to change the default project location:

> Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Locations

[image]

Answer (score 38):

**For VS2013 v4+ and VS2015**

Click on "Settings" (from either the project Home menu or from the top dropdown menu), then select "Git Settings." You will see a Global Setting of "Default Repository Location" (the one you want). Change it and click Update.

Comment: That is for VS 2015, isn't it?

Comment: Just double checked, both 2013 with Update 4 and 2015

Comment: Confirmed - this works with Visual Studio 2017 15.9.

Answer (score 8):

**Visual Studio 2022**
Git repo default location and project default location are not the same thing.

- For default git repo location: **Options -> Git Global Settings -> Default Location**
- For default project location: **Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Locations -> Project location**

Comment: Menu: Git -> Settings -> Default Location

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way to access this in 2019:

1. `Ctrl+Q` to get to quick launch (or click on it at the top of the window)
2. Type `git settings`
   [image]
3. Change Default Location here
   [image]

Answer (score 7):

I am able to access Git Global Settings from Visual Studio "Tools..." menu rather than from Team Explorer:

**[VS2019] => Tools | Options... [Source Control] > Git Global Settings**

(I have not tested it with earlier versions of Visual Studio.)

This works even when you have not opened and/or cloned a Git repos.

[image]

Comment: How is this different from accepted answer?

Comment: The accepted answer requires a GIT repos to be open. Otherwise, there is no "Global Settings" button. This approach is always available.

Comment: I see....you can also (from the menu) just do Git->Settings.

Comment: This answer should have received more votes as well b/c I've noted that Step 3 of the popularly accepted answer isn't always true even when there are cloned Git repos. This method seems to always work regardless of having cloned Git repos or not

Comment: TeamExplorer isn't used in Git repos in later versions of VS2019. This option uses the Git Global Settings and worked.

Comment: It always resets it to put the path back to C:\Users\.... for me. How to stop that? Oh I see. I have to check "Force push --force-with-lease". The question is why? This is a stupid option MS put in Visual Studio - it makes no sense to have to do that in order to save and override the default.