# Can't change default path for repositories git plugin in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

Though I had followed the solution steps of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134077/visual-studio-change-default-path-for-repositories-for-git-plugin#), I still have problems below:

1. My current Default Repository Location setting is C:\Users[User]\Sources\Repos. However, whenever a new project was created, the repository path was set to C:\Users[User]. If I click another empty Local Git Repository in Connect, the new project will be close, Visual Studio backed to Get Started menu.
2. Cause the repository path was set to C:\Users[User], my Visual Studio always has more than 20000 changes, I'm not able to commit and push

I don't know if I've made any change, but how can I fix these problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Simply delete .git folder, .gitattributes and .gitignore files hidden under C:\Users[User] directory. And the Git plugin won't show any changes information of C:\Users[User] path anymore.